# Render partial view with webgrid control via ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am facing issue on my ajax call to render partial view which contains a web grid control. I can't render partialview. What i am doing wrong here

My view where i need to replace with response text using ajax call

```
<div id="searchArea">@{if (Model.SearchResultSupplierViewModels.Count() > 0){ Html.RenderPartial("_SearchResult", Model.SearchResultSupplierViewModels);}}</div>
```

Ajax call to call my partial view

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSearchResultBasedOnFilters", "SearchResult")',
            contentType: 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                supp_fullCheckList: supp_fullCheckList, practice_fullCheckList: practice_fullCheckList, county_fullCheckList: county_fullCheckList,
                state_fullCheckList: state_fullCheckList, ratebase_sliderValue: ratebase_sliderValue, clientRating_sliderValue: clientRating_sliderValue, panelRating_sliderValue: panelRating_sliderValue
            },
            success: function (response) {
                    $('#searchArea').html(response);
                    alert(response);
                },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(status + " : " + error);
        }});
```

Partial view with web grid control

```
 @model List<Panelpartnership.Domain.SearchResultSupplierViewModel>

@{ 
if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "searchArea", defaultSort: "SupplierId");

    grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgrid",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("SupplierId", header: "Supplier Id"),
            grid.Column("SupplierName", header: "Supplier Name"),
            grid.Column("SupplierLocation", header: "Supplier Location")
        )
    );   
}
else
{
    @:There are no suppliers. Please use different filtering conditions for more searching!
}
```

}

Finally my controller

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetSearchResultBasedOnFilters(string supp_fullCheckList, string practice_fullCheckList, string county_fullCheckList, 
        string state_fullCheckList,string ratebase_sliderValue, string clientRating_sliderValue, string panelRating_sliderValue)
    {
        try
        {
            List<SearchResultSupplierViewModel> tSearchResultViewModel = new List<SearchResultSupplierViewModel>();
            tSearchResultViewModel = searchresultmanager.GetSearchResultBasedOnFilterConditions(supp_fullCheckList, practice_fullCheckList, county_fullCheckList,
                state_fullCheckList, ratebase_sliderValue, clientRating_sliderValue, panelRating_sliderValue);

          return PartialView("_SearchResult", tSearchResultViewModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { ok = false, message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Start by removing `contentType: 'text/html; charset=utf-8',`

Comment: `facing issue` what issue? Any errors in console?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I changed but no luck

Comment: @ramiramilu my partial view is not rendering

Comment: `I can't render partialview` are you able to hit the action atleast? Are you going into Success function?

Comment: @ramiramilu Yes, i am getting call to my action. and it also returns with model data

Comment: Try to `$('#searchArea').html('');` and then `$('#searchArea').html(response);`

Comment: @ramiramilu tried but no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81177/discussion-between-ramiramilu-and-nithin-paul).

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @ramiramilu yes i did. The problem was with my webgrid control. Any way you guys really helped to figure out the problem. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The proble was with my webgrid control. When i alterd my webgrid control, the problem gone. This is the updated code

```
@model List<Panelpartnership.Domain.SearchResultSupplierViewModel>

@{
if(Model != null && Model.Count()>0)
{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5,
    selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "searchArea");
        grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);

         @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("SupplierId", "Supplier Id"),
            grid.Column("SupplierName", "Supplier Name"),
            grid.Column("SupplierLocation", "Supplier Location")
     )) 
}
else{
    <label>No suppliers to display!</label>
}
}
```